# 2-of-3 USB Data Backup

Tags: usb, backup, encryption, usb-flash-drive, privacy

I have 3 usb sticks and have data that needs to be backed up securely.

The 3 USB-Sticks will all be stored in different places and I want NO files to be recoverable from just one stick - I want it to be so, that i need at least 2 of the 3 usb sticks to get the original data, how can i do that?

Also it would be nice if the data stored on there would be encrypted with a password.

Comment: The terms USB stick & backup do not belong in the same sentence. You're trying to devise a method of losing your data faster than ordinarily. If you put all the data on all 3 sticks, encrypted, then you have a far better chance one of them will survive, so long as you don't lose the encryption key.

Comment: Also, see https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/security.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use [Parchive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) or Parity Archive.

It is ostensibly a file rebuilding and recovery program intended for archiving systems where reliability is an issue. It can make it possible to recover a missing part of an archive assuming enough parity data is available.

As a result all you would need one of the main archives, then the parity information could be used to rebuild the other archive. The result fills your conditions.

1. Archive 1 + Archive 2 = data recovered
2. Archive 1 + Parity = Archive 2 recovered = data recovered
3. Archive 2 + Parity = Archive 1 recovered = data recovered

In order to make no data recoverable you would probably have to do an extra initial archive up of your incoming data **with encryption**, split that archive into (say) 1MB pieces, and then put the odd numbered pieces in archive 1 and the even pieces in archive 2. (Slight paranoia step)

You would then write half the recovery password in a text file in archive 1 and the other half in a file in archive 2. That way the person holding archive 1 cannot decrypt their blocks without archive 2 and vice versa.

After that you would then create the parity information to create your third recovery stick.

Using Parchive (the third stick) would allow either the first or second stick to be recreated, the archives joined back together, then decrypted, and then the data extracted.

If my thinking is right then the data would be unrecoverable unless one person holds any two of the three sticks.

How to actually automate the entire process is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt your data first (with a randomly generated passphrase), then make 3 identical copies of the data, *then* use a program that implements [Shamir's secret sharing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_secret_sharing) scheme to split the encryption passphrase in "X out of Y" shares, and copy each share to one USB stick. (Copy the programs to the USB sticks as well.)

Optionally, encrypt each share again with your regular passphrase.

Shamir's scheme is only practical for small amounts of data such as encryption keys, but as far as I know it is provably secure, and a decent encryption mechanism will take care of the actual data.